# I am trying to install GIT trough NPM. But it giving me following Error

Tags: git

cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyINt.png)

Comment: Okay, so use the official git installer.

Comment: Are you wanting to use it in a project, or for general use (like developing)?

Comment: Consider opening an issue https://github.com/lzrski/npm-git-install/issues?

Comment: thanks you.@Amy. Installig git solve my problem.

Answer (score -1):

cb() never called! **Solved!**

Please Don't use sudo to install node, npm and packages!

### Downloading and installing Node.js and npm

To publish and install packages to and from the public npm registry or your company’s npm Enterprise registry, you must install Node.js and the npm command line interface using either a Node version manager or a Node installer. We strongly recommend using a Node version manager to install Node.js and npm. We do not recommend using a Node installer, since the Node installation process installs npm in a directory with local permissions and can cause permissions errors when you run npm packages globally.

**Official NPM Docs**
https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm

**Official NVM repository** 
https://github.com/creationix/nvm